# php not displaying results on database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with 4 tables. (products,purchase,customer,user). When I tried to display all rows in `products`, no results. But in the `user` table, it displays. What should be the problem? Is it on my database?tables?php code?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "prodpurchase");
if (!$db) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "select * from user");
if( $sql === FALSE ) {
  die('Query failed returning error: '. mysqli_error());
} else {
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
   {
    echo $row['username']. "<br>";
   }
}
?>
```

Hope you could help me.

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: I think you are mixing up some words here.  You say you have a database with 4 columns when a database doesn't have columns.  A table has columns.

Comment: @DevangRathod: no error..empty results..

Comment: Can you show your products table query ?

Comment: @JohnPeter: no results..as in white plain interface.

Comment: @judda: My bad man. I've already updated my post.

Comment: I feel like there's not enough info to give an answer here. And you updated your code to the query you said was already working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the letters uppercase and lowercase in table columns?

Answer (score 1):

You have inventory in your code, but in your question you named the table products, Is it this simple?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $row['item']. "<br>";
```

What is 'item'?  Shouldn't you be selecting them by $row[0] or $row['products'].. or one of your other columns.

Answer (score 0):

check your variables, for your example, try renaming your vairable `$sql` to something else, because you might have a similar variable somewhere in your code that you did not show.

try this :

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "prodpurchase");
if (!$db) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$sqlstackoverflow = mysqli_query($db, "select * from user");
if($sqlstackoverflow === FALSE ) {
  die('Query failed returning error: '. mysqli_error());
} else {
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlstackoverflow))
   {
    echo $row['username']. "<br>";
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: @scarface23 Thank you for the reply, but I will leave my answer as it is because sometimes this could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code references an `inventory` table but you said your database has a `products` table (and no `inventory` table).  Because of this, the query is failing.

Comment: What is your query that is wrong?  Is there any errors that are being emitted?

Answer (score 0):

***Just Try With The Following :***

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prodpurchase");
if (!$db) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"select * from user");
if( $sql === FALSE ) {
  die('Query failed returning error: '. mysqli_error());
} else {
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
   {    
    echo $row['username']."<br>";    
   }
}
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.